# Create asynchronous sequence with fixed size or timespan elapsed

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observer-pattern

The next method is invoked multiple times per second and I have to notify a subscriber when a number of events have arrived or if a timespan has elapsed:

```
public async Task SendEventsAsync(IEnumerable<Event> events)
{
    foreach(var event in events)
    {
        // Notify my subscriber
    }
}
```

The method belongs to a singleton and will be invoked throughout the application life.

I don't want notify one at a time. I'd like to wait for a large amount of this data before notify my observer (e.g. 10000 items), and if a certain amount of time has elapsed since the last notification, notify too (e.g. every minute). Actually I don't need to send my event objects to the subscriber, just notify that a new bunch of events have received.

I have been trying out Reactive Extensions and I think maybe it could help me:

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));

var idealBatchSize = 10000;
var maxTimeDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
source
   .Buffer(maxTimeDelay, idealBatchSize)
   .Subscribe(buffer => 
        Console.WriteLine("Buffer of {1} @ {0}", DateTime.Now, buffer.Count));
```

This code creates an infinite sequence with a constant interval of time and then is projected to a buffer with a fixed size and a maximum dalay time, something similar to what I'm looking for. But my sequence should be feed from my method instead of a fixed interval of time.

I don't know how my pieces should fit together, what kind of Observable sequence do I need to create. Or maybe I am focusing wrongly on the problem.

Could a sequence with an interval and a static counter be enough?

Comment: SendEventsAsync{} returns Task. When would the tasks returned be completed? For example, if 1000 events are saved for batch delivery, would all 1000 tasks complete immediately, or when the events actually get delivered?

Comment: Inmediately. I don't call this method. It's a contract with a framerwork. The framework call this method to notify me events. Really, the parameter of the method is a IEnumerable<Event>, it forms his own batches before call the method, but I simplified this because I didn't want mix these batches of mine and that was not well understood. I edited my post to show it.

Comment: would setting `var source = events;` work?

Comment: The events parameter hasn't the size I need for my batches. Nor does it have the frequency I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. I'm assuming you have this structure:

```
public class EventNotification { }

public class SingletonThing
{
    //don't need async for Rx
    public void SendEventsAsync(IEnumerable<EventNotification> events)
    {
        foreach (var element in events)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

All you need to do is pipe the events into an observable, then you can use `Buffer` to batch them as you want:

```
public class SingletonThing
{
    private readonly Subject<EventNotification> _subject = new Subject<EventNotification>();
    public void SendEventsAsync(IEnumerable<EventNotification> events)
    {
        foreach (var element in events)
        {
            _subject.OnNext(element);
        }
    }

    //not necessary to expose, but could be helpful
    public IObservable<EventNotification> AllEvents => _subject.AsObservable();

    private int idealBatchSize = 10000;
    private TimeSpan maxTimeDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    public IObservable<IList<EventNotification>> BatchedEvents => _subject
        .Buffer(maxTimeDelay, idealBatchSize);
}
```

The subscribe code would then be invoked as follows:

```
SingletonThing.BatchedEvents.Subscribe(buffer =>
    Console.WriteLine("Buffer of {1} @ {0}", DateTime.Now, buffer.Count)
);
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. I've tried it and it works.